# MVC - Pass custom parameters to a custom action filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parameters, class-library, actionfilterattribute

My solution contains class library project as business library, and I have written a custom action filter in it.

```
public class SampleFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var parameters =filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
        var currentAction = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
    }
```

My requirement is now to pass some other parameters to OnActionExecuted function (like Username, description that I will save in database).

My controller action in MVC application project looks like:

```
 [SampleFilterAttribute]
    public ActionResult PurchaseRequisition(int? ID)
    {
```

So how can I pass some custom parameters to OnActionExecuted() Action Filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a parameter to your custom Filter Attribute via `TempData`, see below:

**SampleFilterAttribute**

```
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
        var controllerName = actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
        var actionName = actionDescriptor.ActionName;
        var userName = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
        var timeStamp = filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp;

        var parameters = filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"]; 
        var description = filterContext.Controller.TempData["Description"];

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

**Action**

```
    [SampleFilter]
    public ActionResult PurchaseRequisition(int? id)
    {
        TempData["Description"] = "This is Description";
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Lin, Although I can access the data now using Tempdata[], but I can't use filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name or filterContext.HttpContext.Timestamp, maybe because I'm writing this code in separate class project. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you have multiple layers in your solution, I suggest you add the custom action filter attribute to your Web layer. Create a folder call "Helper" then add all of custom attribute and extensions to that folder. The directly should same to Controller and View.